# Kaizala: Error: Failed, Response action cards cannot be sent through portal

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

I have created a Form for my department users to collect their data, when I shared the form for that group it shows that **Error: Failed, Response action cards cannot be sent through portal**
Though Kaizala intended for mobile first organisation, having a management portal should be useful to do the same tasks that we do in kaizala mobile app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using Kaizala webapp - https://webapp.kaiza.la/.

However, currently Kaizala webapp is available in select preview. You can write to us @ kaizaladev@microsoft.com to gain access.